# how to render partial view inside a for loop so i can save all rows?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, for-loop, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview, renderpartial

I just started MVC and I'm having troubles on saving and IList model to database. I have a for loop, looping through a list as suggested by all the posts i've read on how to save multiple items inside the model. However, I cannot see examples or articles on how i can render a partial view just by passing a parameter

This was the original code. Which returns null model on submit.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
            { 
                Html.RenderPartial("_Budget", item); 
            }
```

And this is the current code which I found from the suggestions. But I can't  figure out how i can render the partial view every loop. Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
            { 
                Html.RenderPartial("_Budget", item); 
            }
```

Comment: You cant (at least not without some hacks). Use an `EditorTemplate` so that you form controls are correctly named with indexers. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `@Html.Partial`

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{ 
   @Html.Partial("_Budget", item); 
}
```